# WebRTC: Detecting muted track faster post warm-up

Tags: webrtc

I'm warming up my transceiver like so:

```
pc.addTranceiver('video')
```

This creates a dummy track in the transceiver's `receiver`. Soon after, the `unmute` event fires on that track.
Then, ~3 seconds later, the `mute` event fires.

My goal is to detect that a track is a dummy track as fast as possible.

ideas

- send a message via the data channel telling the peer that the track is void. this is a pain since i'll have to send another message when I later call `replaceTrack`
- write a frame of the track to canvas & see if it's an image. This seems really barbaric, but it's faster than 3 seconds.

anything better? it feels like this should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=889487) (please ★ it so they'll fix it).

The spec says receiver tracks must start out `muted` and should *stay that way until packets arrive*. But Chrome fires the `unmute` event immediately, followed a few seconds later by a `mute` event due to inactivity ([another bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=941740)):

```js
const config = {sdpSemantics: "unified-plan"};
const pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

pc1.addTransceiver("video");
pc2.ontrack = ({track}) => {
  console.log(`track starts out ${track.muted? "muted":"unmuted"}`);
  track.onmute = () => console.log("muted");
  track.onunmute = () => console.log("unmuted");
};

pc1.onicecandidate = e => pc2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => pc1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc1.onnegotiationneeded = async e => {
  await pc1.setLocalDescription(await pc1.createOffer());
  await pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription);
  await pc2.setLocalDescription(await pc2.createAnswer());
  await pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription);
}
```

In Chrome you'll see incorrect behavior:

```
track starts out muted
unmuted
muted
```

In Firefox you'll see correct behavior:

```
track starts out muted
```

#### Chrome workaround:

Until Chrome fixes this, I'd use [this workaround](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/6734h1ty/):

```js
const video = document.createElement("video");
video.srcObject = new MediaStream([track]);
video.onloadedmetadata = () => log("unmuted workaround!");
```

Until this fires, assume the track to be `muted`.

Comment: great snippet! leaving this open to fish for possible workarounds

Comment: fantastic! thank you @jib (for the workaround & your awesome blog posts)